# Are memory-mapped files really files?

Tags: file, memory

If I create a memory mapped file and write some text to it, does that file behave like a filesystem file. I.e. does it have an extension?

If it does, does that mean I can create Excel files in memory, pictures and do I have to take the format of the file into consideration when working with it?

Or does it not have an extension and is just a glorified blob of text that persists in memory?

Comment: If we're talking Windows (which I assume we do with the mention of "Excel" and "extension"), there is no such thing as a memory-mapped file. There is such a thing as a *file mapping object*. "Memory-mappedness" is not a property of files, and extensions are not properties of file mapping objects. If your file mapping object is backed by the page file (not a specific file on disk), then whether or not that file has an extension isn't really relevant, since applications won't be able to read the data as if it was a file anyway.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I am talking specifically about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files . So am I right in assuming it's just a blob of text and, like you say, not really a "file" so much as a bunch of data in memory?

Comment: If we're talking file mappings backed by the paging file, then effectively yes, it's a bunch of data -- but in *virtual* memory, which is an important distinction, because it means it wouldn't be correct to assume the data stays resident in physical memory -- it can be paged out. In any case it wouldn't be a file that can be opened as one by applications, though. (Also, files in Windows don't actually have a type and in that sense they're *all* just blobs of bytes -- extensions are just a convention to communicate what's in the file, but there's no explicit MIME type (unlike some OSes).)

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the part about the MIME is interesting, I didn't know that. Final question - since a file mapping backed by the paging file is just a bunch of data, does that mean I can still manipulate it, like, for example create a PNG image in memory and operate with it as an image, without opening it as if it was a file?

Comment: Yes, as long as your code supports it. If you had an application that was specifically designed to read the PNG image from a file mapping (and knew it was expecting a PNG image), you could share data that way (in fact, sharing data between application without having to go through disk is the reason file mappings backed by virtual memory are a thing), but to something like Paint it's inaccessible (because Paint only opens files, not file mapping objects).